# Using DataFrame Index Dates for Date Column Creation

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to reduce the code bloat in my project for the process of creating various date columns (weekday, business day, day index, week index) and I was wondering how I can take the index of my dataframe and build datetime attribute columns from the index.

I thought I could access the `.index` or `index.values` and then reference the datetime attributes like `month`, `weekday`, etc., but it doesn't appear that `Index` has those attributes. Would I need to convert the index values to a new list and then build the columns off of that?

Here is my code:

```
historicals = pd.read_csv("2018-2019_sessions.csv", index_col="date", na_values=0)
type(historicals)

// date formate = 2018-01-01, 2018-01-02, etc.

# Additional Date Fields
date_col = historicals.index
date_col.weekday

// AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'weekday'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index is in string format. You `historicals.index` probably looks like this

```
print(historicals.index)

Index(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02'], dtype='object')
```

You need to convert it to datetimeindex and get its `weekday` attribute and assign to new column

```
historicals['weekday'] = pd.to_datetime(historicals.index).weekday
```

Or

```
date_col = pd.to_datetime(historicals.index)
print(date_col.weekday)
```

Comment: That was exactly it. The index was actually in `date` format, but same issue. Only way to resolve it was to convert to datetime. Thank you!